# Compare the rows in excel and highlight the difference

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to excel macro and I am trying to compare the values in `sheet1` with values in `sheet2` and the difference should be updated in `sheet3` and highlight the values that are "False".

I am using the **`EXACT`** function for comparison as `=EXACT( Sheet1!A1, Sheet2!A1 )`.

Range of cells from A1 to DJ70.

Can you please help to create a macro by getting the number of values from the user and compare that particular number of rows. For example, if user specifies 10 in the input box, the 10 rows should be compared. Please help me in this regards.

Sorry for not providing the code. I tried the below code by giving the range. But I need to know how to get the values from the user and compare that particular number of Rows.

```
Sub compare()
     Sheet3.Activate
     Range("A6").Select
     ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=EXACT(Sheet1!R[-5]C,Sheet2!R[-5]C)"
     Range("A6").Select
     Selection.Copy
     Range("A6:DJ70").Select
     ActiveSheet.Paste
     Range("A6").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I do something like this...
I'll show you what I do, then you can copy it to your business

I have one column with same names and everytime that I put a name that I already have, I mark another column as unique or repeated.

For this, I use this formula
=IF(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$100; $B$2:$B$100)=1;"Unique";"Repeated");

Let me try to explain:

```
NAME-COLUMN | UNIQUE-COLUMN
---------------------------
JORGE       | UNIQUE
JOHN        | REPEATED
ROBERT      | UNIQUE
MARIA       | UNIQUE
JOHN        | REPEATED
```

Just check if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

## Code:

```
Sub Compare()
    Dim mx As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    On Error GoTo ErrHandling

ReDo:

    mx = CLng(InputBox("Enter Number of Rows to Search:", "Entry Required: ...", 1))

    If mx < 1 Or mx > 70 Then
        MsgBox "Please Enter a valid number of rows!"
        GoTo ReDo
    End If

    For i = 1 To mx

        Sheet3.Range(Sheet3.Cells(i, 1), Sheet3.Cells(i, 114)).FormulaR1C1 = "=EXACT(Sheet1!RC, Sheet2!RC)"

    Next i

    Exit Sub

ErrHandling:

    If Err = 13 Then
        MsgBox "Rows must be a number!"
        GoTo ReDo
    Else
        MsgBox "An Unexpected Error Has Occured!"
    End If

End Sub
```

### Theory:

Simply loops through the rows indicated and all columns filling in the formula you use.

Comment: Thanks Jbarker2160. It works the way I expected. Thousands of thanks. Now I want, not to limit the column comparisons. Can you please advise how i can try not to limit the columns.

Comment: That's a bit more difficult.  You simply have to use the column counts from `Sheet.UsedRange` from Sheet1 and Sheet2 and use the larger one for the last column in your comparison.  Please mark this with the green check to indicate that I answered your original question.